# How to parse below file contents

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I have below file contents and need to do validations like "CPU State" is up for all rows and "HA State" active for all except for type v-mcm where it's active and standby both. Any help will be appreciated. I am trying split based on "\t" and trying to create some key/value pair.

cluster
     SLOT    CPU                                ADMIN    HA       CPU

### ID   NUMBER  NUMBER  TYPE   PERSONALITY  MODEL  STATE    STATE    STATE

102  1       1       v-csm  CSM          vCSM   enabled  active   up
     2       1       v-csm  CSM          vCSM   enabled  active   up
     5       1       v-ssm  SSM          vSSM   enabled  active   up
     6       1       v-ssm  SSM          vSSM   enabled  active   up
     7       1       v-mcm  -            vMCM   enabled  standby  up
     8       1       v-mcm  -            vMCM   enabled  active   up

Comment: The `pandas` library will be very handy here. You can read the file into a DataFrame and do your operations on it. `pandas.read_csv(filepath, header=None, sep="\s+")`. The first row of your sample data is 9 columns but the rest are 8 columns. Is this as it is?

Comment: Thank You Very Much...Have a Nice Time :)